# Auto creating subfolders in box.com through salesforce

Tags: apex, after-trigger

Below is my code for auto creating the folders in opportunity but it is throwing me the below error for my code...

> Error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Code:

```
public void createboxfolders(){

   box.Toolkit boxToolkit = new box.Toolkit();

         for(Opportunity Op : newOppsList){

             if(!boxfolderIdset.isEmpty()){

              String opportunityFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolderForRecordId(op.Id, null, true);
        system.debug('new item folder id: ' + opportunityFolderId);

        // Create two sub-folders in the newly created account folder
        String QuoteFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolder('Quote', opportunityFolderId, null);
        system.debug('Quote Folder id: ' + QuoteFolderId);
        String NewBusinessFormFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolder('New Business Form', opportunityFolderId, null);
        system.debug('New Business Form Folder id: ' + opportunityFolderId);

        // Collaborate the current user on the account folder. Note that we're sending false for the optCreateFolder param that shouldn't actually matter since the folder(s) already exists 
        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        box.Toolkit.CollaborationType collabType = box.Toolkit.CollaborationType.EDITOR;
        String collabId = boxToolkit.createCollaborationOnRecord(userId, op.Id, collabType, false);
        system.debug('new collaboration id: ' + collabId);

        // ALWAYS call this method when finished. Since salesforce doesn't allow http callouts after dml operations, we need to commit the pending database inserts/updates or we will lose the associations created
        boxToolkit.commitChanges();   
             }
         }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? None of the lines you posted here seem to contain any query, so it seems unlikely this code is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your example, I don't see any queries so either your code sample is not complete or the error is inside of box.toolkit. If box.toolkit is code inside of a managed package then you'll need to contact the developer for support.
Below is a general description of the error, how it occurs and how to avoid it. If you adjust your patterns you'll be able to make sure you never introduce the error yourself.**

The List has no rows for assignment error generally means you are running a query that is returning 0 results and trying to assign it directly into an SObject variable.

Queries generally return lists of records, not just a single record. When you assign a list to an individual variable like so:

```
Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
```

The backend does a little extra work for you. The extra work can be made to look like:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
if (accounts.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception('List has no rows for assignment to SObject');
} else {
    return accounts[0];
}
```

In this example, the issue is that `accounts[0]` would return an index out of bounds error. Salesforce is trying to help you by telling you that your query is returning no results to make the error a little more understandable.

My advice to get rid of the error is to always assign query results to lists:

```
Account a;
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
if (!accounts.isEmpty()) {
     a = accounts[0];
} else {
     // Handle error, maybe display to vf page?
     return;
}

// do stuff with a
```

### Note:

Obviously don't ever `[select Id from account]` in your code, always use a where clause to limit results.